# Scala Anorm. Insert exception; parameter index out of range

Tags: database, scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

Trying to insert user data to DB. Checked all the parameters, data is correct, but it still throw the exception

`java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).`

The code is like this

```
DB.withConnection {
      implicit c =>
        SQL( """"
          insert into tUser (fname, lname, fullname, avatarurl, email, extuid, service)
          values ({fname}, {lname}, {fullname}, {avatarurl}, {email}, {extuid}, {service})
             """).on(
           'fname -> socialUser.firstName,
           'lname -> socialUser.lastName,
           'fullname -> socialUser.fullName,
           'avatarurl -> socialUser.avatarUrl.getOrElse(Option.empty),
           'email -> socialUser.email.getOrElse(Option.empty),
           'extuid -> socialUser.id.id,
           'service -> socialUser.id.providerId
         ).executeUpdate()
     }
```

Tried to use H2, now I use MySQL, but have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't work. The statement starts with four double quotes but it should be tree.

> SQL( """"

Though I don't know about the `socialUser` object, I tried a simpler example and it worked with H2.

Comment: Absolutely stupid mistake. Thank you. I've spent whole day for this bug :(